# Winston 3.x support for logstash missing?

Tags: node.js, logging, logstash, winston, elk

I'm trying to integrate a dummy nodejs app to an ELK stack. I'm using winston as logging library since it's my preferred choice when I develop on a JS stack. I've tried to write this sinppet of code, using winston 3.x version

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-logstash');


var logger =  winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.Logstash({
            port: 5000,
            node_name: 'my node name',
            host: '127.0.0.1'
        })
    ]
});

logger.info('ciao mondo')
```

The result was

```
> node index.js

logstash is a legacy winston transport. Consider upgrading: 
- Upgrade docs: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md
```

So I've read the official instructions which state that the logstash support is now a format

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-logstash');


var logger =  winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format : winston.format.logstash(),
    transports: [
         new winston.transports.Console()/*,
         new winston.transports.Logstash({
           port: 5000,
           node_name: 'my node name',
           host: '127.0.0.1'
         })*/
      ]
  });

  logger.info('ciao mondo')
```

Now the output is

```
> node index.js

{"@message":"ciao mondo","@fields":{"level":"info"}}
```

Which is ok, but since I've not told how to connect with logstash socket, the centralized logging system didn't receive this event.

I've tried downograding winston to 2.4.1 and it works fine, excpet for the fact that I'm loosing some good feature introduced in the laters versions. I've not found any documentation that informs about logstash support on 3.x version. Am I missing something or I have to write something custom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two concepts at play here, in Winston 3.

A *format* just does some transformations on the object you're logging.

A *transport* is a "pipe" that defines a way of taking your log object and sending it somewhere.

In the Winston 2 world, these two concepts were often combined; for instance, the `winston-logstash` module was a transport but also implicitly formatted objects in a way that's acceptable for Logstash.  There's nothing in Winston 2 or 3 that restricts what is possible in terms of transports or formats, so Winston 3 is not "missing support" for Logstash.

However, Winston 3 *did* make some changes to the transport API (and also separated out formats, as mentioned - though a transport *can* still do formatting).  That is why you see warnings about `winston-logstash` being a legacy transport: the authors of `winston-logstash` have not updated their module to use the new Winston 3 style interfaces.  There is a [thread](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1331) on the Winston project with some helpful info for transport authors on updating their transports.

So, you could bug the authors to upgrade their transport, upgrade/wrap it yourself (see linked thread), or - I think the `legacy` warning is just a warning, so it should still work ok with Winston 3.

In fact, I think there is already a [PR](https://github.com/jaakkos/winston-logstash/pull/52) open to make `winston-logstash` 3.x compatible, though the repo maintainer seems to have ghosted; I suppose you could try using the PR branch/fork.  You might also try [winston-logstash-transport](https://github.com/liuyanjie/winston-logstash-transport) which appears to achieve the same goals but appears to be designed for 3.x.  Feel free to comment on what works best.

Comment: Thank you davewy for your thorough answer! I can confirm that the API change broke the compatibiltiy with winston-logstash. I've discarder winston-logstash-transport too early because it seemed very less widespread than the other but, actually, the first listed seems no longer maintained. I will report my feedback with   winston-logstash-transport. Is important for the Winston community to have an easy integration with ELK stack!

Comment: Were you able to use  winston-logstash-transport successfully? after integrating winston-logstash-transport instead of winston-logstash, my logs are not transporting to logstash instance

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this guide [here](https://dev.to/deleteman123/logging-at-scale-done-right-3m0e) on how to use winston with the `winston-elasticsearch` plugin. This produces logs that are in the logstash format and therefore consumable by Kibana.

## `winston-elasticsearch` info

### Features

1. logstash compatible message structure.
2. Thus consumable with kibana.
3. Date pattern based index names.
4. Custom transformer function to
   transform logged data into a different message structure.
5. Buffering
   of messages in case of unavailability of ES. The limit is the memory
   as all unwritten messages are kept in memory.

### Compatibility

For `Winston 3.x`, Elasticsearch `6.0 and later`, use the `0.7.0`. For Elasticsearch `6.0 and later`, use the `0.6.0`. For Elasticsearch `5.0` and later, use the `0.5.9`. For earlier versions, use the `0.4.x series`.